# Pegar datas do banco , e "Destaca-las" em um Calendário Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Eu tenho um código com duas datas que vão marcar algo, como um evento de uma semana por exemplo, uma é a data de inicio do evento e a outra a data de encerramento desse evento, para facilitar a visualização do usuário eu quero botar essas duas datas em um calendário (Datepicker), porém eu não tenho ideia de como fazer para mostra a data de Inicio e de encerramento no meu calendário, tem como fazer isso?

Aqui ele está pegando as datas e as exibindo em tabela junto com alguns outros valores

```html
 <?php
                include 'phpfiles/connect.php';

                $sql = "SELECT Campanha, DATE_FORMAT( Data_inicio, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS Data_inicio, DATE_FORMAT( Data_fim, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS Data_fim, Thumbnail, Descricao FROM walldata limit 0,10";
                $result = $con->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        ?>
                        <tbody>       
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= $row['Campanha'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['Data_inicio'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['Data_fim'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['Thumbnail'] ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="phpfiles/edit.php?Campanha=<?= $row['Campanha'] ?>">Edit</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="phpfiles/Delete.php?Campanha=<?= $row['Campanha'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro?');">Delete</a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

E aqui ta o calendário( Peguei da internet porque não conheço muito bem js)Da pra ver os dia selecionados, é assim que eu queria que ficasse, é como se a data1 fosse o dia 1 e a dois fosse o dia 4, entenderam?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Calendário jQuery</title>   

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#calendario").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Data: <input type="text" id="calendario" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Atualmente estou usando datepicker que pega a data do pc, da de pegar a dos valores do banco?

Comment: Mas você quer apenas que o usuário selecione as datas que estão no  intervalo da  data de início e fim ou você quer deixar essas datas apenas destacada ?

Comment: Bom na verdade, tem um cadastro que ele vai cadastrar o evento e o tempo de duração, esses dados serão armazendos no banco de dados, depois eu quero exibilos em um calendário, a data de inicio e a de fim, varios ao mesmo tempo, n se preocupe com a validação de datas iguais em diferentes eventos eu arrumo isso posteriormente.

Comment: @LucaoA Só exibir as datas que já estão no BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esses casos eu utilizo o [Datepicker Range](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range), como você já utiliza o Datepicker acredito que não terá nenhum problema.

[Aqui](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) tem uma versão mais bonita dele.

Comment: Isso ajudará de fato, mas teria como deixar o calendário sempre a vista tipo sem precisar selecionar as datas, e também colocar varias datas diferenter que marcam outros evento no mesmo calendário?

Comment: Para deixa-lo sempre visível basta chama-lo em uma div `<div id="datepicker"></div>`. Para carregar o calendário com uma data selecionada você pode definir na declaração um "defaultDate". Porém, se for necessário selecionar mais de um data (que não seja range), pode testar o [MultiDatesPicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Mas não daria de fazer só para exibir as datas, não precisa alterar, só quero exibir? :D

Comment: Entendi, você quer apenas mostrar os dias agendados. Então poderia declarar o MultiDatesPicker já com as datas pré-selecionadas e usar o jQuery para marca-lo como ReadOnly.